# Display nested JSON file in Angular

Tags: json, angular, nested

I can't wrap my head around how I should loop through a nested JSON file I've got.

This is the code I've got si far:

JSON:

```
[
    {  
    "produkt": "dammsugare",
    "produktinformation": [
        {
        "artikelnr": 9121283726,
        "typ": "ean"
        },
        {
        "artikelnr": "dasu",
        "typ": "varukod"
        }
    ]
    },
    {
    "produkt": "hammare",
    "produktinformation": [
        {
        "artikelnr": 91246128736,
        "typ": "ean"
        },
        {
        "artikelnr": "traffaspik",
        "typ": "varukod"
        }
    ]
    }
]
```

Service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyserviceService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getProducts() {
    console.log('getProducts()');
    return this.http.get('/assets/produkter.json');
  }

  getInfo() {
    console.log('getInfo()');
    return this.http.get('/assets/produkter.json')
  }
}
```

Component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MyserviceService } from '../myservice.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.scss']
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  arrProducts: any;

  constructor(private myserviceService: MyserviceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myserviceService.getProducts().subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.arrProducts = data;
    });
  }
}
```

Component.html:

```
<p>list works!</p>
<ul *ngFor="let product of arrProducts">
    <li>{{ product.produkt }}</li>
    <li>{{ product.productinformation.artikelnr }}</li> <!-- THIS LINE IS WRONG, BUT I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO DO-->
</ul>
```

As you can see, I do not know how to edit the component.html for it to display the nested JSON file.

I hope there's someone who could help me out. Thanks! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just nest `ngFor`...

```
<p>list works!</p>
<ul *ngFor="let product of arrProducts">
    <li>{{ product.produkt }}</li>
    <li *ngFor="let info of product.produktinformation">{{ info.artikelnr }}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON structure says `productinformation.artikelnr`, but you want to access `produktinformation.artikelnr`, i. e. you misspelled a **c** and wrote **k** instead.